# What formula do I use to get the answer from sheet 2, column B into sheet 1, column R, by having the part number be the only link to both sheets?

Tags: excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXeMd.jpg)What formula do I use to get the answer from sheet 2, column B into sheet 1, column R, by having the part number be the only link to both sheets?

I need to get the pre-set cost value in sheet 2 into an ever-changing sheet 1 spreadsheet. The cost stays the same-sheet 2 is my legend, but different numbers are in-putted into sheet 1 all the time, and I want the cost to automatically populate from sheet 2 into sheet 1. Each number needs a cost.

Example:

**Sheet 1**:

```
Column A    Column R
3568        (need formula to = 7.30)
1660        (need formula to = 1.50)
```

**Sheet 2**: Numerical-Once and a while new numbers will be added

```
Column A    Column B
0270        2.20
1660        1.50
2610        8.00
3568        7.30
```

Where 0270 = 2.20, 1660 = 1.50, and so on...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at the [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) function.  It will do exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I've actually researched it a bit before posting my question. I can't seem to grab the correct price. Something in my formula isn't correct. I have tried two different ways, and it is grabbing a price from somewhere that doesn't make sense.

=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1,$A$1:$A$3,0)),"",LOOKUP(A1,'SHEET2'!$A$1:$A$3,'SHEET2'!$B$1:$B$3))

or

=VLOOKUP($A5,'SHEET2'!$A1:$C1000,2)

Answer (score 2):

Try this formula in column R, starting in row 2

```
=vlookup(A2,Sheet2!$A$1:$C$1000,2,False)
```

If you omit the last parameter, it defaults to TRUE, which requires the data to be sorted and will return an approximate match if no exact match is found.

Also, if you copy the formula down, make sure that the lookup range has absolute references for columns AND rows, i.e. `Sheet2!$A$1:$C$1000` and NOT `Sheet2!$A1:$C1000`

Comment: Also adding, since OP's vlookup failed (although it's probably that last parameter default). Sometimes there is trailing whitespace in one of your lists. Make sure you don't have any spaces hanging out after your numbers in column A of both lists.

Comment: So I did it, and out of 5 of my part numbers, I only did a small area for testing. It only populated the correct price for the 4th part. All the others are N/A. Is this where you think there might be whitespace? Seeing as one of my parts did it correctly?

Comment: N/A means the value is not found in the list. You need to check that the value exists. If you are sure it does, check that the formula references the correct range.

Comment: I attached a link to my question.

Comment: As far as I can see none of the numbers in sheet 1 are in sheet 2. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Sorry, they are there, just lower down in my report, I only attached the partial as an example. They have identical format to the ones shown in Sheet 2.

Comment: On a row where you think there should be a result, but instead you see N/A, do this: compare that column A value with the value on sheet 2 that you think is a match. Don't just eyeball it. Use a formula like `=Sheet1!A50=Sheet2!A25` -- Does that return TRUE or FALSE?

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to, but thank you! It came up FALSE, but then I noticed some numbers weren't being saved as numbers, but as text. I switched that around and the formula works now.